# Google maps plugin

Tags: plugin-recommendation

Please recommend a google maps wp plugin that can put a map inside a wp page while other text will be situated near it (right or left hand side).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Google Maps Embed](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-maps-embed/) and use CSS to float the iframe.

Nice plugin. It gives you a button in the MCE Editor of Wordpress. You simple paste your maps url!

Comment: The best and most practical.

Answer (score 2):

I have been happy with Mappress.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mappress-google-maps-for-wordpress/

Comment: I'm a big fan of MapPress, it makes it easy for the "non-Googler" to easily add their own maps as well.

Comment: Didn't like this one, it made me ask this question. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iFrame to embed your Google Map on a custom WP page and some custom CSS to float some text to the right or left side too.

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend [Google Maps v3 Shortcode](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-maps-v3-shortcode/). I used it in a project to show a Google map with many placeholders (positions read from a dynamic kml file).

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/geolocation/ ? 
Its loading map only when visitor hovering link. And you dont need to style your page for google map